# how to place some text on image and saving the image with text using jquery / html5 / php

Tags: php, jquery, html5-canvas

Hi am working on one small task which is related to generating a greeting card in this i need to select an image and select a text from provide texts i need to put selected text on image and save it and send to the users,i want to do it in html5,jquery,php.

Any suggestions

Comment: did you try anything??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php, it's called "watermark".

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```